# User created instance

Tags: python, class

I am trying to complete a homework assignment about python classes that has a few requirements:
Your program will prompt the user to create at least one object of each type (Car and Pickup). Using a menu system and capturing user input your program will allow the user the choice of adding a car or pickup truck and define the vehicle's attributes. The program will use user input to define the vehicle's attributes.

The options attribute in the parent class must be a python list containing a minimum of eight (8) options common to all vehicles.

The user will choose from a list of options to add to the vehicle's options list and must choose a minimum of one vehicle option per vehicle. When the user is finished adding vehicles to their virtual garage the program will output the vehicles in their garage and their attributes.

I haven't started on the child classes yet because I want to make sure the parent class works as needed before adding more.

My program kind of works but I have to create the instance manually.

My question is, how do I make a user-inputted instance so that I can make repeat entries?

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, make, model, color, fuelType,options):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.fuelType = fuelType
        self.options = options
            
    def getMake(self):
        self.make = input('Please enter the vehicle make: ')
        

    def getModel(self):
        self.model = input('Please enter the vehicle model: ')
        

    def getColor(self):
        self.color = input('Please enter the vehicle color: ')
        

    def getFuelType(self):
        self.fuelType = input('Please enter the vehicle fuel type: ')
        

    def getOptions(self):
        optionslist = []
        print('\nEnter Y or N for the following options')
        radio = input('Does your vehicle have a radio: ').lower()
        bluetooth = input('Does your vehicle have bluetooth: ').lower()
        cruise = input('Does your vehicle have cruise control: ').lower()
        window = input('Does your vehicle have power windows: ').lower()
        lock = input('Does your vehicle have power locks: ').lower()
        mirror = input('Does your vehicle have power mirrors: ').lower()
        rstart = input('Does your vehicle have remote start: ').lower()
        bcamera = input('Does your vehicle have a back up camera: ').lower()

        if radio == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Radio')
        if bluetooth == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Bluetooth')
        if cruise == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Cruise Control')
        if window == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Power Windows')
        if lock == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Power Locks')
        if mirror == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Power Mirrors')
        if rstart == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Remote Start')
        if bcamera == 'y':
            optionslist.append('Backup Camera')

        self.options = optionslist    


#creates instance
selection1 = Vehicle('n','n','n','n','n')


Vehicle.getMake(selection1)
Vehicle.getModel(selection1)
Vehicle.getColor(selection1)
Vehicle.getFuelType(selection1)
Vehicle.getOptions(selection1)

#makes sure options list has at least one option
if not selection1.options:
    print('\nYou need to select at least one option.')
    Vehicle.getOptions(selection1)


print(f'Your vehicle is a {selection1.color} {selection1.make} {selection1.model} that runs on {selection1.fuelType}. The options are ' + ", ".join(selection1.options) +'.')


Outputs:
Please enter the vehicle make: ford
Please enter the vehicle model: f150
Please enter the vehicle color: grey
Please enter the vehicle fuel type: gas

Enter Y or N for the following options
Does your vehicle have a radio: y
Does your vehicle have bluetooth: y
Does your vehicle have cruise control: y
Does your vehicle have power windows: y
Does your vehicle have power locks: y
Does your vehicle have power mirrors: n
Does your vehicle have remote start: n
Does your vehicle have a back up camera: n
Your vehicle is a grey ford f150 that runs on gas. The options are Radio, Bluetooth, Cruise Control, Power Windows, Power Locks.
```

Comment: Move the input statements outside

Comment: Whatever function you use to elicit options from the user needs too return a class instance - `return Vehicle(make, model, color, fuelType, options)`

Answer (score 0):

Your various `get*` methods would make a good class method.

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, make, model, color, fuelType,options):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.fuelType = fuelType
        self.options = options

    # As already defined
    def getMake(self): ...
    def getModel(self): ...
    def getColor(self): ...
    def getFuelType(self): ...
    def getOptions(self): ...


    @classmethod
    def get_from_user(cls):
        # Initialize the "template" vehicle
        v = Vehicle("", "", "", "", [])

        # Configure the template
        v.getMake()
        v.getModel()
        v.getColor()
        v.getFuelType()
        v.getOptions()

        # Return the configured vehicle
        return v
```

Then you can create an instance with one method that handles all the user prompts

```
v1 = Vehicle.get_from_user()
```

or by getting the values yourself and passing them directly to `Vehicle` as arguments.

```
v2 = Vehicle("ford", "f150", "grey", "gas", ["Radio", "Bluetooth"])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we have to use various get methods to follow a specific class breakdown. The various get methods are required functions.

Comment: Ugh. Just be aware that it's a *terrible* class design, at least in Python.

Comment: How does the user create the instance though? I have a feeling the instances need to be stored in a list or dict so they can be retrieved as needed but not sure how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I show you two examples of how the instances are created. `v2` doesn't require any user interaction; you can supply whatever values you like as the arguments. If you want a list of, say, 5 instances, you can do something like `vs = [Vehicle.get_from_user() for _ in range(5)]`. This doesn't have anything to do with the definition of `Vehicle`, though.

Comment: Apologies, I'm pretty new to coding.  The instances should only be created when the user needs them.  So if the user adds one vehicle, then only one instance should be created. If the user adds 4 vehicles, then 4 should be added.  I may be misunderstanding but the way you showed, the instances are predetermined by the code.  I hope that makes sense.  I have gotten a bit further on it by using lists and loops.  Is there a way to post my updated program and output?